# googletest-ing several files

Tags: c++, file, googletest

I want to test my code for fibonacci sequence that is written in separate files(instructions!), but i don't know how to compile.

fib.h:

```
#ifndef FIB_H
#define FIB_H
#include <gtest/gtest.h>


class fib
{
public:
    int fibRec(int n);
};

TEST(testFib, firstTest)
{
    fib fibnumber;
    EXPECT_EQ(55, fibnumber.fibRec(10));
    EXPECT_EQ(13, fibnumber.fibRec(8));
    EXPECT_EQ(89, fibnumber.fibRec(11));
    EXPECT_EQ(3, fibnumber.fibRec(5));
}

#endif // FIB_H
```

fib.cpp:

```
#include "fib.h"

int fib::fibRec(int n)
{

    if(n <= 0) return 0;
    if(n == 1) return 1;
    else return(fibRec(n-1)+fibRec(n-2));

}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <limits>
#include "fib.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
   return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

My `libgtest.a` is in `/home/me/gtest` and `include` is in `/home/me/gtest/gtest-1.7.0/include`.
I tried to compile and run the test in terminal with g++ like this, but it didn't work

```
$ g++ -c fib.cpp
$ g++ -c fib.h
$ g++ -c main.cpp
$ g++ -I/home/me/gtest/gtest-1.7.0/include -pthread main.cpp libgtest.a -o test_exe
```

What am I doing wrong or rather what should i add?

**EDIT:**

I tried `$ g++ -I/home/me/gtest/gtest-1.7.0/include -pthread main.cpp fib.cpp libgtest.a -o test_exe`

but I got an error

```
/tmp/ccTTfKeF.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `testFib_firstTest_Test::test_info_'
/tmp/ccq6EExi.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccTTfKeF.o: In function `testFib_firstTest_Test::TestBody()':
fib.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `testFib_firstTest_Test::TestBody()'
/tmp/ccq6EExi.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile and link your object files in order to be able to run your program:

```
g++ -I/home/me/gtest/gtest-1.7.0/include -pthread 
     main.cpp 
     fib.cpp 
     libgtest.a -o test_exe
```

And, most importantly, **you need to move the test body from the header into your main.cpp file**

```
//main.cpp
#include <limits>
#include "fib.h"

TEST(testFib, firstTest)
{
    fib fibnumber;
    EXPECT_EQ(55, fibnumber.fibRec(10));
    EXPECT_EQ(13, fibnumber.fibRec(8));
    EXPECT_EQ(89, fibnumber.fibRec(11));
    EXPECT_EQ(3, fibnumber.fibRec(5));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
   return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

you're defining the function body multiple times violating [ODR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Comment: i got an error, i edited original post with the report

Comment: The test should probably belong in its own .cpp file as per the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_7_Primer#Setting_up_a_New_Test_Project). By the way, `g++ -c fib.h` creates a precompiled header file, which is probably not your intention.

Comment: @remyabel I just started to mess around with -c and -o switches... If i move the test in a separate file, should i just add a `#include <test.cpp>` in `main.cpp`? and when compiling+linking just add the `test.cpp` behind `-pthread`?